# Passing Nullable Values from Activity to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arguments, bundle

When passing `Strings` from an activity to a fragment using

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString(key, value);
fragment.setArguments(args);
```

I can also pass potential `null` and receive it in the fragment with

```
String string = getArguments().getString(key);
```

I'd also like to pass nullable `Float`s and `Integer`s but the corresponding `putInt()` and `putFloat()` methods don't allow passing `null`. I am now passing additional flags as arguments that indicate whether a value is set or not but that seems rather clumsy in comparison. Is there a better way to pass potential null values (preferably available in API level 14 and later)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to skip putting something in case of `null` into bundle.
In fragment just check `Bundle.containsKey(String key)`, if doesn't means `null`.

Comment: Good point. That saves the flag. The `get...` methods actually do this check and allow defining a default value that of course cannot be null. But this works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Kotlin version of @Eugene Krivenjas textual solution - just in case someone prefers copy/pasting to thinking ;)

```
private fun Bundle.putLongOrSkip(key: String?, value: Long?) =
    apply { value?.let { putLong(key, value) } }

private fun Bundle.getLongOrNull(key: String?) = 
    if (containsKey(key)) getLong(key) else null
```

Ofc this is possible for `floats` and `ints`, too.